# C# LINQ Query with dynamic operators

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following LINQ query

```
var productGroupFilterValue = Convert.ToInt32(filterList.Where((filter) => filter.InternalName == "ProductGroup").FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
var productsData = (
            from 
                artikel in impGgContext.ArtikelTable
            join 
                wgober in impGgContext.WgoberTable on new { parameter1 = artikel.Wgober } equals new { parameter1 = wgober.Wg_Ogrp }
            where 
                (productGroupFilterValue != 0 && artikel.Wgober == productGroupFilterValue)
            select new Database.DTO.QueryResults
            {
                ProductId = artikel._Kenn,
                ProductNo = artikel.Nummer,
                ProductSearchName = artikel.Such_e,
                ProductName = artikel.Text_f.GetNameFromContainer(Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Language.English)),
                ProductGroupNo = artikel.Wgober,
                ProductGroupName = wgober.Langtxt.GetNameFromContainer(Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Language.English)),
                ProductStatusNo = artikel.Prodstat
            }
            ).ToList();
var list = productsData.ToList();
```

Actually the `productGroupFilterValue` is being queried with `==`.
But the user have the option in the GUI to select between "Equals" (`==`), "Greater than" (`>=`) and "Contains".

The selected operator option is part of the `filter` object and called `filter.Operator`.

Is there a way to implement this in my LINQ query dynamically?

Comment: You can compose queries from parts (as long as you stay in the `IQueryable` world). Read up on _Predicate Builder_ fir examples: https://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: How can I implement the `predicate` into my linq query. I cannot load all data first and then apply the predicate on the results. That would not be effiicient.

Comment: Until you materialize the IQueryable (with a foreach or a ToList or something) all you have is an IQueryable. And queryables are composable

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to achieve this can be through expression trees like this: I am not sure but i hope this gives you an idea.

```
    var operatorMap = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>
{
    {"==", (x, y) => x == y},
    {">=", (x, y) => x >= y},
    {"contains", (x, y) => x.ToString().Contains(y.ToString())}
};

var filter = filterList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.InternalName == "ProductGroup");
if (filter != null && int.TryParse(filter.Value, out int productGroupFilterValue) && operatorMap.TryGetValue(filter.Operator, out var comparisonFunc))
{
    var productsData = impGgContext.ArtikelTable
        .Join(impGgContext.WgoberTable, a => a.Wgober, w => w.Wg_Ogrp, (a, w) => new { a, w })
        .Where(x => operatorMap[filter.Operator](x.a.Wgober, productGroupFilterValue))
        .Select(x => new Database.DTO.QueryResults
        {
            ProductId = x.a._Kenn,
            ProductNo = x.a.Nummer,
            ProductSearchName = x.a.Such_e,
            ProductName = x.a.Text_f.GetNameFromContainer(Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Language.English)),
            ProductGroupNo = x.a.Wgober,
            ProductGroupName = x.w.Langtxt.GetNameFromContainer(Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Language.English)),
            ProductStatusNo = x.a.Prodstat
        })
        .ToList();
}
else
{
    // handle invalid filter or conversion failure
}
```

Here, we are creating a dictionary that maps the operator strings to lambda functions that perform the corresponding comparisons. and then pass our comparison criteria i.e. ==, >= or contains. If it is available in our dictionary then, we use the lambda function mapped to that key to dynamically construct the comparison expression in the LINQ query. I hope this helps.

Comment: That is a nice idea! One question: You are not using `operatorMap` in the LINQ query, is it possibly a typo and you meant to do `.Where(x => operatorMap(x.a.Wgober, productGroupFilterValue))` instead of `.Where(x => comparisonFunc(x.a.Wgober, productGroupFilterValue))` ?

Comment: Thanks man, you're right.  I have changed the code to fix this issue i guess.

Comment: I do not see here Expression Tree. Maybe `Expression<Func<int, int, bool>>`? Anyway it will not work.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv
 - Can you explain to us why you think it will not work?

Comment: With real Expression Tree the following will be not translatable by EF Core: ` .Where(x => operatorMap[filter.Operator](x.a.Wgober, productGroupFilterValue))`.

Comment: @Utsav Thanks for the solution, but it throws an error on the `Join`. The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Comment: I tried to add a `ToList()` after the `Join`. This seems to work, but I get no results at all

Answer (score 0):

Use switch statement. first retrieve the operator value from the filter object, and then use it in a switch statement to dynamically generate the appropriate filter condition. If the operator value is null, the filter condition is ignored and all products are returned.

Here is example

```
var filter = filterList.Where(f => f.InternalName == "ProductGroup").FirstOrDefault();
var operatorValue = filter?.Operator;
var productGroupFilterValue = Convert.ToInt32(filter?.Value);

// Query the impGgContext database for product data based on the filter criteria
var productsData = (
    from artikel in impGgContext.ArtikelTable
    join wgober in impGgContext.WgoberTable on new { parameter1 = artikel.Wgober } equals new { parameter1 = wgober.Wg_Ogrp }
    where
        // If the operator value is null, return all products
        operatorValue == null || (
            operatorValue == "==" && artikel.Wgober == productGroupFilterValue ||
            operatorValue == ">=" && artikel.Wgober >= productGroupFilterValue ||
            operatorValue == "Contains" && artikel.Wgober.ToString().Contains(filter.Value)
        )
    
    select new Database.DTO.QueryResults
    {
        ProductId = artikel._Kenn,
        ProductNo = artikel.Nummer,
        ProductSearchName = artikel.Such_e,
        ProductName = artikel.Text_f.GetNameFromContainer(Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Language.English)),
        ProductGroupNo = artikel.Wgober,
        ProductGroupName = wgober.Langtxt.GetNameFromContainer(Convert.ToInt32(Enums.Language.English)),
        ProductStatusNo = artikel.Prodstat
    }
).ToList();

// Convert the productsData to a list and assign it to the variable "list"
var list = productsData.ToList();
```